# How to save data.frames respectively in a list?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Here's my question. It's really appreciated if you can help. 
I have a list containing several data.frames with different length but the same structure. 
Now I want to save the data.frames in the list respectively. 
Note: not combine them using do.call(rbind,...) into one single data.frame. And Also I want to name each of the data.frame in a array.

```
a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6)

b=c(4,5,6,5,5,5)

c=c(3,4,5,6,7,8)

A=data.frame(a=a,b=b,c=c)

B=data.frame(a=c,b=b,c=a)

C=data.frame(a=b,b=c,c=a)

l <- list(A, B, C)

names.list <- c("NewYear_Data", "Thanks_giving", "Christmas")
```

Now I want to save the A B C in the list using the name in names.list

To be specific, Here I have a list l, in which have several data.frames. Now I want to save each data.frames in the list l using the name in the names.list.

I tried unlist, and get, and apply...

It would be great if anyone can solve this using plyr, reshape, or data.table methods.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is not perfect in the code you presented? I miss what is it what you did not achieve.

Comment: Hey Andrey, I edited a little bit:) Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: It's really not clear where you want to end up. Perhaps `list2env` might be of use to you? (Or, maybe it's as easy as `names`, as Andrey suggests in his answer.)

Comment: What do you mean by "respectively"? I get the feeling that the word doesn't have the same meaning for you that it does for most of us reading your question. Do you mean in alphabetical order or some other kind of specified order?

Comment: I just want to get rid of the list..

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution

```
l <- list(A, B, C)
nms <- c("NewYear_Data", "Thanks_giving", "Christmas")
names(l) = nms
```

Now you can use names like this:

```
l$Christmas
```

If you want to get rid of the list, do this:

```
attach(l)
Christmas
```

To save them in a binary file:

```
save(list=nms,file='file.Rdata')
```

Or in a text files:

```
for( i in 1:length(l))
  write.csv(l[i],paste0(nms[i],'.txt'))
```

Note to avoid calling your variable `names`.

Comment: Thanks Andery, you are so helpful. Maybe I didn't explain it clearly. Here I want to same the data.frame **respectively**. That is I want Christmas, I want Thanks_giving, and I want NewYear_Data. Could you offer some suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer with the `attach` option. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks Andrey! Sorry for that I don't have enough reputation to vote up...Here we are closer to what I want. Now I want to save the data.frame respectively for each data.frame attached.

Comment: What do you mean by save? (Updated the answer)

Comment: Thanks again for your help! I want to use the data.frame in the list in the following analysis. So I want to get rid of the list...Actually I read the rdata file containing the list and want to extract the data.frame. Is that clearer now?

Comment: Oddly, I want to apply the same function to a list of dataframes and it does not work `for(i in seq_along(l)){save(l[i], paste0(names(l[i]), '.RData'))}`. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

If the question is, "How do I save a list of data frames as separate files in a folder?", you may try using `saveRDS` rather than `save` ([see here](http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2012/04/01/saving-and-loading-r-objects/)).

```
names(l) <- names.list

lapply(names(l), function(df) 
  saveRDS(l[[df]], file = paste0(df, ".rds")))

list.files(pattern = ".rds")
[1] "Christmas.rds"     "NewYear_Data.rds"  "Thanks_giving.rds"

# To load an individual dataframe later 
df <- readRDS(file = "NewYear_Data.rds")
```

If you want to use save, the following should work ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26853234/how-to-use-saverds-in-a-loop-with-the-object-names-being-passed-as-variables-r); noting that `save` preserves variable names, hence the `with` statement and use of `list =`).

```
with(l, 
     lapply(names(l), function(df) 
       save(list = df, file = paste0(df, ".rda"))))

list.files(pattern = ".rda")
[1] "Christmas.rda"     "NewYear_Data.rda"  "Thanks_giving.rda"
```

Otherwise, you can save the entire list as a single file

```
save(l, file = "Holidays.Rda")
```

Answer (score 1):

Working with a single list with named elements is almost always preferable to working with lots of objects in your workspace. However, two functions that may be of convenience to acheive your aims are `setNames()` and `list2env()`. The following line will create named `data.frame` objects in your global environment using the names in `names.list`...

```
list2env( setNames( l , names.list ) , .GlobalEnv )
```

`setNames()` is a convenience function that sets the names on an object and returns the object. `list2env()` assigns each element from a named list into the specified environment so you end up with 3 `data.frame` objects.

Answer (score 0):

After running your code, we have:

```
> ls()
[1] "a"          "A"          "b"          "B"          "c"          "C"         
[7] "l"          "names.list"
```

You can then `assign` the data.frames to the names in `names.list`:

```
> invisible(mapply(function(x, y) assign(x, y, envir=globalenv()), names.list, l))
> ls()
[1] "a"             "A"             "b"             "B"             "c"            
[6] "C"             "Christmas"     "l"             "names.list"    "NewYear_Data" 
[11] "Thanks_giving"
> Christmas
a b c
1 4 3 1
2 5 4 2
3 6 5 3
4 5 6 4
5 5 7 5
6 5 8 6
> NewYear_Data
a b c
1 1 4 3
2 2 5 4
3 3 6 5
4 4 5 6
5 5 5 7
6 6 5 8
```

Then, if you want to clean up your workspace and remove what you used to create the data, you can run the following (careful, this will remove EVERYTHING in your workspace, except the data frames we just created):

```
> rm(list=ls()[!(ls() %in% names.list)])
> ls()
[1] "Christmas"     "NewYear_Data"  "Thanks_giving"
```

Frankly, I would recommend @Andrey's answer with attach, but if you're really looking to get the data frames to be in your workspace and get rid of the stuff you used to create it, this is an option.