# How to make a functional list with the data.frames from the environment in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, merge

I want to join several data.frames in one. All the data.frames share an identical column.

There are [different ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096814/merging-a-lot-of-data-frames) to merge several datasets and since I am using this approach `Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=TRUE), list(  ))` I need to get a list of the data.frames that I have in the environment.
However, every time that I try to get a list of them, the features of being a data.frame disappear and they are only saved as a names.

These are my dataframes:

```
file_1 <- women
file_2 <- women
colnames(file_2) <- c("height_2", "weight_2")
file_3 <- women
colnames(file_3) <- c("height_3", "weight_3")
file_4 <- women
colnames(file_4) <- c("height_4", "weight_4")
file_5 <- women
colnames(file_5) <- c("height_5", "weight_5")
```

Since I want to merge them, I need to add the same column to all of them.
With the first line of code, I make a list of the variables that I have in the environment (I only want the data.frames which start with the name "file")

```
list_files <- grep("file",names(.GlobalEnv),value=TRUE)

for (file in list_files){
  temp <- get(file)
  # We add the column 
  temp$ID <- "col"
  #we return the change in the file
  assign(file, temp)
}
rm(temp) #we don't need it anymore.
```

However, when I try to use `list_files` (which has the name of the data.frames) in order to merge them, I don't get a proper data.frame merged.

```
DF_complete <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=TRUE), list(list_files))

> class(DF_complete)
[1] "character"
```

On the other hand, when I try this code (I write all the dataframes myself), I get the dataframe that I want.

```
DF_2 <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=TRUE), list(file_1, file_2, file_3, file_4, file_5))

class(DF2)
[1] "data.frame"
```

I want to avoid writing all the data.frames. Right now I have 5 data.frames, but when I have more than 10.... it will be tough. For that reason, I want to find another way.

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20812132/how-to-save-data-frames-respectively-in-a-list) and I have tried this, but they are not saved as data.frames.

```
list_df <- list(list_files)
> list_df
[[1]]
[1] "file_1" "file_2" "file_3" "file_4" "file_5"
class(list_df)
[1] "list"
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: Can you save all your dataframes into an object (list) instead of the global environment?

Comment: @user2974951 How do you suggest doing it? My original problem is that I load "RData" files, so I take them from a path, remove the pattern "RData" and then I load them into the environment... For that reason I was thinking about how to merge them from the environment...

Comment: Do you create those RData files? Do you save the dataframes into the global environment there already? Can you save them into a list before saving the RData file?

Comment: @user2974951 First of all I load individual .tsv files, then I save each of them in .RData objects (just in case the original file get corrupted) and I worked with those RData files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we have multiple data.frames in the global environment that we want to merge, we can use `mget` and `ls`:

```
file_1 = data.frame(id = c(1,2), a = c(1,2))
file_2 = data.frame(id = c(1,2), b = c(3,4))
file_3 = data.frame(id = c(3,4), a = c(5,6))

Reduce(\(...) merge(..., all = T), mget(ls(pattern = "file")))
  id a  b
1  1 1  3
2  2 2  4
3  3 5 NA
4  4 6 NA
```

Comment: @Eva the example I used is to show how `merge` works - it fills `NA` where no value is found when merging. When the `id` column in `file_3` is made into `1:2`, the `NA` would just shift to another position in the resulting data.frame. To see how different joining operations work, I suggest running the following code: `purrr::reduce(mget(ls(pattern = "file")), dplyr::full_join)`, refer to `?dplyr::full_join`, and try replacing `full_*` with `inner, right, left, anti`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! I didn't know about `mget` and `ls`!

Comment: And sorry for the question that I made before, I deleted it because I finally understood later. Sorry for the mess. And thanks very much again for your answer!